# RethinkDB query filter against multiple values for single key

Tags: dynamic, rethinkdb

Heres my example db with 3 rows in it

```
{type:"a", info:""}
{type:"b", info:""}
{type:"c", info:""}
```

Using rethink db how would i list all types of value a or b

// Here was my first solution but i can't dynamically build it

```
r.table("example").filter(r.row("type").eq("a").or("b")).run(conn, function(err, results){...});
```

so if the next time i want types a and c i'm in trouble. I need a way to build a query. The cookbook example doesn't really make sense to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `r.row('type').eq('a').or('b')`, but that doesn't do what you expect.

You probably want `r.row('type').eq('a').or(r.row('type').eq('b'))`

You could also write `r.expr(['a', 'b']).contains(r.row('type'))`

Answer (score 1):

I found that since filter is just an object i could just have

```
var filter;
filter = r.row("type").eq('a');
```

and if i want to add more to it then you just add on an and/or op to the filter.
    filter = filter.and(...);

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to provide a filter function that uses [match](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/match/) to test the value against a Regular Expression.

```
let query = r.table('yourdata').filter(row => row('yourfield').match('a|b'));

query.run(conn).then(results => { ... }).catch(err => { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, it is much easier to use [filter](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/filter/) and [match](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/match/) as @besworks suggests.

In RQL Data Explorer syntax:

```
r.db("groceries").table("fruit")
  .filter(r.row("type").match("apples|bananas|grapes"))
```

This allows for simple chaining and logic gate expressions:

```
r.db("groceries").table("fruit")
  .filter(r.row("type").match("apples|bananas|grapes"))
  .filter(
    r.row("kind").match("fuji|concord").and(
    r.row("kind").match("plantain|gala|cotten_candy").not()
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this because I find myself coming back to this post 10 times a year and never getting the answer efficiently.

```
r.db("db").table("table").filter(function (user) {
  return r.expr(['a', 'b']).contains(user('type'))
})
```

I will thank myself later.

Comment: I already said thank you to myself 5 times.